# Use Gmail api for send mail via Android app

Tags: android, gmail-api, credentials

I know there are a lot of toturials, questions etc and I was working on it at the past weeks but couldn't figure it out.

I am developing an Android app that I want to send an email to some email address, using my gmail account.

I have read all the Google Developers Documentation and tried all the examples but still can't achieve it.

**1. First of all** - do I have to own a G Suite account? it doesn't say that I do, but the [Gmail Api overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) is under G Suite section??

If I don't need a G Suite -

**2.** Is this the [right guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) to send mail by app?

If so

**3.** How can I get the `Gmail service`? I opened a project in `console.developers.google` and got the `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` json file, but I couldn't find an explanation how to use it in Android to get the credentionals.

Please, I know those are big question but I am desperate for help. Please give me any answers or correct links (that I haven't visit yet...). I also will appreciate help via chat / mail etc.

Thanks

**EDIT 8/10**
**my code right now:**

**Main Activity**
calls AsyncMail

**AsyncMail.java**

```
package com.send.mymailapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Base64;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class AsyncMail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    Context context;

    static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    public AsyncMail (Context c) {
        context = c;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground (String... strings) {


        try {

            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream jsonStream = assetManager.open("mail.json");

            // those 2 tryings also works but gave me the same error
            /*ServiceAccountCredentials sourceCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(jsonStream);
            sourceCredentials = (ServiceAccountCredentials) sourceCredentials.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam"));

            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(jsonStream).createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM));
            Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();*/


            GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(jsonStream)
                           .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow", GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM));
            credential.refreshIfExpired();
            AccessToken accessToken = credential.getAccessToken ();
            String AuthToken = accessToken.getTokenValue ();


            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter (credential);


            Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer).build();

            MimeMessage mimeMessage = createEmail ("avitalh@gmail.com", "sendmail@mail-291708.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "subbb", "bodyyyy");

            Message message = createMessageWithEmail(mimeMessage);

            gmail.users().messages().send ("sendmail@mail-291708.iam.gserviceaccount.com", message).execute();


        } catch (IOException | MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    private Message createMessageWithEmail (MimeMessage emailContent) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        emailContent.writeTo(buffer);
        byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
        Message message = new Message ();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
    }

    public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String bodyText) throws MessagingException {

        Properties props = new Properties ();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress (from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }
}
```

I also not sure:

1. Which credentials should I get? I would think it is `ServiceAccountCredentials` but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) says to use `GoogleCredential` which is deprecated so I tried `GoogleCredentials`
2. Which email address shoud I use as the sender - the gmail? the sevice account? "me"? there are 2 places that I should use it
3. What should I do with the token?
4. At the top of the Google Api Console it says "Your free trial is waiting: activate now..." - I must activate the account to use the api? I don't think so but not sure

Comment: do you know the answer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738316/using-android-googlesignin-with-gmailscopes-gmail-send-gmail-api

Comment: sorry @user3505444, I have no idea. I gave up using Gmail to send mails... I use another 3rd party for it

Comment: This is crazy, the documentation in the past years looks like big 0. google are heading in the wrong direction. once I'll figure it out, I'll post the reply.

Comment: @user3505444 Yes, it is CRAZY. If we can't count on Google, what's left?... Good Luck to you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your multiple question

1. **No**, you don't need a G Suite account to use the Gmail API, you can do it with a normal *gmail* account.
2. The guide that you linked is fine, just think that inside an app or in a console, the API works over HTTPs request with a REST architecture, therefore you can use the API in any platform that support HTTP requests.
3. This last bit will depend highly on the architecture you are using, and take into consideration that I'm not an Android expert. But the "difficult" part will be to get the authorization from the user, but I believe you can do it normally with Java.

#### Useful links

- [G Suite for Android](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android)
- [Google Services sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services)
- [Authenticate OAuth2 in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate#java)
- [JAVA Gmail API quicsktart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!

About answer 3, as I wrote, I want to use **my** account for sending the mail so I don't need the user permission, right?
I just couldn't find how to get the credentials.


You really helped me, Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the credentials either way. At what point are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at getting Authorized Gmail API instance for the `public static Message sendMessage` method. All the samples are for picking an use account dialog, when want to use my own. Also, I am not sure - you said I need to use HTTPs request (I can do it with Volley) but it looks like Gmail api doesn't require it, isn't? I am really lost... it is such a basic thing and I can't find any full explanation of it. So much appreciate your patient!

Comment: Account dialog? Take into consideration that the person (in this case you) will need to provide access from the google platform to access your data. I would strongly recommend you to read the article about [OAuth2 in native Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) and also [OAuth in Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)

Comment: I read a lot... I have a basic question: Do I have to won a domain for using the Gmail api for sending emails from *my* account? domain for G suite account or for the consent screen? I can't figure it out!

Comment: No you don' t need a domain, neither a G Suite account. You don' t even need to verify your app if it' s for [personal use](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I read the link you provided and as much as I understand, I don't need to verify my app because I am going to use a service account, right? or I do need a brand verification? it is not clear... Still, I am going to upload it to Google play. I editted my main question above with the code I have by now. It works smooth to the end, but I get 400 Bad Request Failed Precondition, can you please tell me why? I feel like I miss something

Answer (score 1):

Initial steps :

1. **You need to sign in the web browser  with your google account.**

   ***you will get redirect error if you do not***  error 400 etc..
2. **Add app to google cloud platform**,
   add sha-1 key, for **all signatures** you will be using
3. Create a web app with pesky redirected URL !!
   [image]

**The final console will look like this:**
[image]

4. Download  the **web app** credential.json. put it in new folder app/resources
   [image]

   class GmailQuickstart {

   ```
   private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "com.emable.getlabels" ; 
   private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
   private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

   /**
    * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
    * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
    */

   private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList( GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS ) ;
   private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";



   public static Message sendMessage(Gmail service,
                                     String userId,
                                     MimeMessage emailContent)
           throws MessagingException, IOException {
       Message message = createMessageWithEmail(emailContent);
       message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

       System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
       System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
       return message;
   }

    public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage emailContent)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        emailContent.writeTo(buffer);
        byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
    }

   private static LocalServerReceiver localServerReceiver = null;
   private static AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp localAuthorizationCodeInstalledApp = null;

   private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT,Context context, String personId) throws IOException {
       // Load client secrets.
       InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
       if (in == null) {
           throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
       }

       GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

       // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
       GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
               HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
               .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(  context.getFilesDir() )) // new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
               .setAccessType("online")
               .setApprovalPrompt("force")
               .build();
        if (localServerReceiver == null) {
            localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        }else{
            localServerReceiver.stop();
            localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        }

       AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp  lAuthorizationCodeInstalledApp = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localServerReceiver) {
               protected void onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl) throws IOException {
                   String url = (authorizationUrl.build());
                   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                   (context).startActivity(browserIntent);
               }
           };

       return lAuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize("user");
   }

   public static void start(Context c,String personId, TextView tview) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
       // Build a new authorized API client service.

       final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();

       Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,  getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT, c, personId))
               .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
               .build();
       new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c,"Gmail service ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               toast.show();
           }
       });
       Log.i("TAG", "BLA");
       // Print the labels in the user's account.
       String userid = "me";
       ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(userid).execute();
       List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
       //service.
       if (labels.isEmpty()) {
           Log.i("TAG","  No Labels ");

       } else {

           for (Label label : labels) {
               new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, label.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                       toast.show();
                   }
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This function can be called by a button in the Avtivity for example.

```
   public void SendEmailTest(Context context){

       AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
               try {
                   try {
                      // ignore personId, tview your dont  really need them
                       GmailQuickstart.start(context, personId, tview);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               return "";

           };

       };
       asyncTask.execute();





   }
```

Add user permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SMS_RECEIVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "      bla bla bla bla bla your app id here"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

}




dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'



    def billing_version = "4.0.0"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    debugImplementation files('app/libs')
    debugImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"

    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev83-1.23.0'




}
```

change the GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS to [what ever](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/GmailScopes.html)
GOD HELP US ALL

Comment: Good for you!! I've already gace aup and use a 3rd party for sending emails... I think that "GOD HELP US ALL" is a very good summary... :)

Comment: Can we use Android option instead of web application? If we can, how to do it?

Comment: This in an android solution, not web