# GmailQuickstart modification for android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement this in android.

https://github.com/googleworkspace/java-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/src/main/java/GmailQuickstart.java

few questions :
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME  = ...  **is this the android app name?**

**what is the alternative for this in android :**
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156140/use-gmail-api-for-send-mail-via-android-app/68777134#68777134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

full description and working solution is here

[Use Gmail api for send mail via Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156140/use-gmail-api-for-send-mail-via-android-app/68777134#68777134)

basically you need to change few things:
browser Call (within the auth function) to intent.
and remove  all UI calls from do in background process.