# NoClassDefFoundError dependency issues calling Gmail API

Tags: android, gmail-api

I'm trying to access my Gmail from an Android app and am running into dependency issues. I've been following a combination of guides, including the Java Quickstart (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) and a few others on StackOverflow and GitHub.

Whenever I run the emulator, I get a "NoClassDefFoundError", always from a Google API call to AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(). Here's one of them:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lsun/security/action/GetLongAction;
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerConfig.<clinit>(ServerConfig.java:43)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerConfig.getClockTick(ServerConfig.java:100)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<clinit>(ServerImpl.java:50)
        at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:32)
        at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:17)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:111)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:127)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:108)
        at com.example.gmailtemplates.ui.templates.TemplateListAdapter.getCredentials(TemplateListAdapter.java:141)
```

Here's my code that calls it, which I literally copied and pasted from a guide:

```
// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
return credential;
```

My gradle build file includes:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.32.2'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20211108-1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.0'

    ....
}
```

The thing is that I'm pretty sure that sun.net.httpserver is pretty old and no longer used. Am I missing something or using some weird old version of Google API? I'm using Android Studio for the first time, so it's possible that I made some wrong configuration.

Comment: The sample that you linked to is for desktop or server Java, not Android. You would need to find something suitable for Android.

Comment: I was a bit worried about that, but I compared that sample to the second answer on this SO question, which seemed to be specifically for Android. The two samples were pretty much the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156140/use-gmail-api-for-send-mail-via-android-app

Comment: The class that is failing resolution (`sun.security.action.GetLongAction`) is not part of Android. Jetty is a Web server; running a Web server in an Android app is *not* a good idea from a security standpoint unless you really know what you are doing. I assume Jetty is coming from `com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty`, so perhaps you need to switch to some more Android-aware OAuth client.